# Stuck on Stopping System V runlevel compatibility

Tags: login

I tried doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but I cannot login since every time I type at the password field no characters are being input or I just got the wrong username password.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I got this message while installing Ubuntu Server x32 in Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked in French Ubuntu forums, unfortunately to no avail for me, and for some this did work:

You need to verify that your `/home/$USER/.Xauthority` file is not owned by `root`.

You can simply check that with `ls -ld .Xauthority` (assuming you are in the home directory) and revert it back with

```
sudo chown $SUDO_USER .Xauthority
```

Let me know if that helped. I had to reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

I got the problem after I removed GDM. (Running 12.04 with Openbox.) I solved it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to another console and reinstall it.

Should it realy be `$SUDO_USER` or am I supposed to replace it with my username for example? Well, it didn't work anyway. On the other hand, I didn't try very hard.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command works just fine IMHO I had similar problem now its fixed.

```
sudo chown username:username /home/username/.Xauthority
```

Just put your username in place of `username` in the command.

Answer (score 0):

At login:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Enter your password and login.
Worked for me.