# Is it possible to login as root in this situation?

Tags: login, root, login-screen

The Ubuntu server has been not used for about three months and it works not well. When I try to run it the start process stuck on "stopping system V runlevel compatibility". I searched this forum and found and followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184411/stuck-on-stopping-system-v-runlevel-compatibility), and then I got to the login screen by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>. But I don't know the root password and any accounts' name and passwords.

I have tried to break into it without password following [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) by rebooting and pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> key, but it doesn't work. I was told to enter the password or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to continue. 
[not the prompt but passwd needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZkL5.jpg)

Is it possible for me to login in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) when I'm [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO2b2.png) I need to enter <kbd>E</kbd> (don't hit enter) to edit the setting.

And then I navigate to [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HUDZ.jpg) and go to the fourth line(starting with `linux /boot/vm....to revovery \nomodeset`) from the end and replace `recovery \nomodeset` with `quiet splash rw init=/bin/bash`. Last hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to resume the booting, and you'll see a prompt and enter `passwd` to set a new password for root.

Comment: reference: http://www.linuxdiyf.com/linux/6680.html

Comment: can be done too, but not recommend as this is not proper boot. Only usable as last resort

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly easy - http://google.com/?q=ubuntu+reset+forgotten+root+password

Which leads to the well-hidden first entry: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

Comment: No, the <kbd>shift</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: did you try ESC, too? The timeframe sometimes is very small, as in some configurations the grub menu isn't shown due to screen flickering.

Comment: Yeah, the ESC works and I can resume the system following this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password, but it stops in the same place showing "stopping system V runlevel compatibility"

Comment: So, now you should be able to change the root password using the recovery menu item (as described in http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).
after that try Ctrl+Alt+F1or Ctrl+Alt+F2 to login as root.
does that work?

Comment: yeah, I am in the place after entering on root. But it tells me that "give root password for maintenance(or type control-D to continue):" No prompt as said in that link site.

Comment: Try booting an ubuntu usb stick to "try ubuntu" and mount the local hard drive to /mnt. then you can `chroot /mnt /bin/bash` and change the password.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used your sudo user password, would have been enough. Otherwise, not possible, especially if root is disabled( which it is by default on Ubuntu ) . if you need to recover data from it, remove hard drive, use USB to SATA connector ( fairly cheap on Amazon)  to connect it to another computer.

If you have encryption on the drive, you're not gonna get any far. Consider reinstalling the OS